# Failing Linkedin Acthorization token with "r_compliance" permission for accessing Compliance Events API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch the Authorization token along with the permission **r_compliance** to access the Linkedin **Compliance Events API** which failing every time with the message "Could not complete OAuth 2.0 login" on postman client, other permissions are working like **r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress, w_member_social** while generating authentication access token

[image]

Comment: This may not work but it's one of the things I'm trying at the moment: email developer-support@linkedin.com. Back in the v1 API days, that was the way to request this permission. See: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/compliance

Answer (score 0):

Apps seem to list their allowed permissions (the basic 3 you listed) under
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/ > App > Auth > Permissions.

There seems to be no self-service way add a permssions.

I believe the application needs to be approved by LinkedIn to request permission r_compliance or any other permission.

I'm also looking for a way how to apply for the scope at LinkedIn Developer.